# how to insert multiple data fields in one string in mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

i am doing an invoice project using node.js in which i have to store multiple products in a string and my code is

the schema file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
var invoiceSchema = mongoose.Schema({

date: String,
documentNo:Number,
vendorName:String,
pno:Number,
productName:String,
description:String,
quantity:Number,
costPrice :Number,
mrp:Number,
invoiceNo:Number,
advance:Number,
due:Number,
discount:Number,
Tax : String,
netTotal:Number,
size:String,
colour:String,
grandTotal:Number

},{collection:'invoice-data'});

var invoice = module.exports = mongoose.model('invoice',invoiceSchema);
```

now for routing

```
var product = require('../models/product');
var invoice= require('../models/invoice.js');
exports.addaInvoice=function(req, res) {
var date=req.body.date;
var invoiceNo=req.body.invoiceNo;
var vendorName = req.body.vname;
var pno = req.body.orderNo;
var productName = getElementById(req.body.productname);
var description = req.body.desc;
var colour = req.body.colour;
var size = req.body.size;
var quantity = req.body.quantity;
var costPrice = req.body.costPrice;
   var mrp = req.body.mrp;
     var amount=req.body.amount;
     var discount=req.body.discount;
     var discountvalue=req.body.discountvalue;
     var netamount=req.body.netamount;
var advance = req.body.advance;
var due = req.body.due;
var Tax = req.body.Tax;
var netTotal = req.body.netTotal;
var subTotal = req.body.subTotal;
var grandTotal = req.body.grandTotal;

    var newInvoice = new invoice({
            date: date,
            invoiceNo:invoiceNo,
            vendorName:vendorName,
            pno:pno,
            productName:productName,
            description:description,
            colour:colour,
            size:size,
            quantity:quantity,
            costPrice :costPrice,
            amount:amount,
            discount:discount,
            discountvalue:discountvalue,
            netamount:netamount,
            mrp:mrp,
            advance:advance,
            due:due,
            Tax :Tax,
            netTotal:netTotal,
            subTotal : subTotal,
            grandTotal : grandTotal
   });
    newInvoice.save();
            req.flash('success_msg',' purchase invoice added ')
    res.redirect('/users/invoicedetails');
```

}

html code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculate()
 {
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
    var costprice = document.getElementById('costprice');

    //var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
var result=quantity.VA*costprice.value;
    //amount.value = result;
$("#amount").val(result);

  }</script>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }


</SCRIPT>

</head>




<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="date">date</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<input id="date" name="date" placeholder="date" class="form-control input-md" type="date">

</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="invoiceNo">invoiceNo</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<input id="invoiceNo" name="invoiceNo" placeholder="invoiceNo" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

</div>
</div>
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="vendorname">Vendor name</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<select id="vendorName" name="vendorName" class="form-control">
     {{# each items }}


    <option> {{ this.vendorName}}</option>
       {{/each}}


</select>
</div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Product " onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<table class="table table-hover" >
<thead>
   <tr>
       <td>productno</td>
       <td>productName</td>
       <td>size</td>
       <td>colour</td>
       <td>quantity</td>
       <td>costprice</td>
       <td>MRP</td>
       <td>amount</td>
       <td>discount%</td>
       <td>discount value</td>
       <td>net amount</td>
   </tr>
 </thead>
```

```
<TABLE id="dataTable" class="table table-hover" >
    <TR>


    <td>

    <input id="orderNo" name="orderNo" placeholder="productno" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
  </td>
```

```
              {{# each items }}


               <option value="{{ this.productid}}"> {{ this.productname}}</option>
                  {{/each}}

     </select>

     </td>
     <td>
          <select id="size" name="size" class="form-control-md">
           {{# each items }}


            <option > {{ this.size}}</option>
               {{/each}}


         </select>

     <!-- Text input-->
   </td>
   <td>
       <select id="colour" name="colour" class="form-control-md">
         {{# each items }}


          <option > {{ this.colour}}</option>
             {{/each}}


       </select>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control " type="text">

  </td>
   <td>
     <input id="costPrice" name="costPrice" placeholder="costPrice" class="form-control" type="text"  onChange="calculate()">

   </td>
   <!-- Text input-->
   <td>

     <input id="mrp" name="mrp" placeholder="mrp" class="form-control" type="text">
   </td>
   <td>

 <td>
     <input id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="amount" class="form-control" >

   </td>
<td>
     <input id="discount" name="discount" placeholder="discount%" class="form-control"type="text">

</td>
   <td>

     <input id="discountvalue" name="discountvalue" placeholder="discountvalue" class="form-control"type="text">

   </td>
   <td>
     <input id="netamount" name="netamount" placeholder="netamount"  class="form-control"type="text">

   </td>
       </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<!-- Text input-->
<td>
<label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="advance">Advance</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input id="advance" name="advance" placeholder="Advance" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="Tax">Tax</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select id="Tax" name="Tax" class="form-control">
  <option value="14.50">14.10</option>
  <option value="12.50">12.50</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</table>
</table>

<label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="netTotal">netTotal</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input id="netTotal" name="netTotal" placeholder="netTotal" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

</div>

<label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="subTotal">SubTotal</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input id="subTotal" name="subTotal" placeholder="subTotal" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
```

```
<label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="grandTotal">grandTotal</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input id="grandTotal" name="grandTotal" placeholder="grandTotal" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
```

```
<label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="due">due</label>
<div class="col-md-4" align="left">
<input id="due" name="due" placeholder="due" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

</div>


<!-- Button -->

<div class="form-group" align="bottom">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="vadd"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button id="iadd" name="iadd" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my html code in it the script is for cloning of the table for addingg a row in the tablle for multiple product entry

now this will work for one product if i have 2 or more products

how can i save these three products in a same document as like purchase invoice

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  To help you get the best possible answer, please use this SO Question Checklist to reformat your question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bodyParser middleware, then you can pass an array of values from the client-side.

On client-side you might need to name your input elements as follows

```
<input name="products[#{1}][productname]" type="text">
<input name="products[#{1}][description]" type="text">

<input name="products[#{2}][productname]" type="text">
<input name="products[#{2}][description]" type="text">
```

and so on

This way your request body will have

```
{
    "products": {
        "1": {
            "product name": "name goes here ",
            "description": "desc goes here "
        },
        "2": {
            "product name": "name goes here",
            "description": "desc goes here"
        }
    }
}
```

You can iterate through that and get the values in your router as

```
var products = Array.prototype.slice.call(request.body.products);
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    var newInvoice = new invoice({
        productName: products[i].productname,
        description: products[i].description
    });
    newInvoice.save();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and i want to know how to store 'n' no of products

Comment: you have mentioned code like this from client side

    <input name="products[#{1}][productname]" type="text">
    <input name="products[#{1}][description]" type="text">

    <input name="products[#{2}][productname]" type="text">
    <input name="products[#{2}][description]" type="text">

if i put
   <input name="products[#{i}][productname]" type="text">
   <input name="products[#{i}][description]" type="text">

what is the loop to be written

Comment: You can use a 'for each' kind of loop on the client side and name the elements using the loop index

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your invoice schema to add multiple products in it. You need to add a array of product sub documents, I have added a sample schema below

```
// Product Schema 
var ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    pno:Number,
    productName:String,
    description:String,
    quantity:Number,
    costPrice :Number,
    mrp:Number,
    size:String,
    colour:String,
});


var invoiceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   date: String,
   documentNo:Number,
   vendorName:String,
   products: [ProductSchema],
   invoiceNo:Number,
   advance:Number,
   due:Number,
   discount:Number,
   Tax : String,
   netTotal:Number,
   grandTotal:Number
},{collection:'invoice-data'});
```

I haven't checked this code syntactically, I am just giving you an idea how to create schema if you want to store multiple sub documents in a single document.

And in your node.js code also, you need to save an array of products

```
var productArr = [];
var temProduct = {};

temProduct.pno= pno;
temProduct.productName= productName;
temProduct.description= description;
temProduct.colour= colour;
temProduct.size= size;
temProduct.quantity= quantity;
temProduct.costPrice = costPrice;
temProduct.amount = amount;
temProduct. = mrp;


productArr.push(temProduct);
var newInvoice = new invoice({
        date: date,
        invoiceNo:invoiceNo,
        vendorName:vendorName,
        products:productArr,
        advance:advance,
        due:due,
        Tax :Tax,
        netTotal:netTotal,
        subTotal : subTotal,
        grandTotal : grandTotal
   });

  newInvoice.save(function(err, new_data) {
      if(err) {
          // Handle error here, if any come
      } else {
          req.flash('success_msg',' purchase invoice added ')
          res.redirect('/users/invoicedetails');
      }
  });
```

You can push as mush as products you want in productArr, then add it in invoice object and then save it.

I am mentioning again, that above code is not good to run directly, you need to do few changes, but it will give you an idea how to do it.

Comment: thanks for giving the answer But the in the above code in the array only one product data is storing i made some changes also but it is not working i want some  'n'  of products to be saved

Comment: if i add one product  it is saving   and if i add two or more products only the id is storing

Comment: The schema i mentioned works for me fine, so may be you are missing something in input code.
Can you update your code in question, and put the code where you are trying to save multiple products, Then may be i can help.